# Cannot connect to the MongoDB server from node by using the environmental system variables set in Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker image using a node and a mongodb image but I cannot set the environmental variables from the Dockerfile or docker-composer.

Dockerfile:

> FROM node
>
> RUN mkdir /app
>   WORKDIR /app
>   COPY package.json /app
>
> RUN npm install
>   COPY . /app
>
> ENV MONGODB_URI 192.168.99.100/myapp
>
> EXPOSE 3030
>
> CMD ["npm", "start"]

docker-compose.yml:

> version: "2"
>
> services:
>
> web:
>
> ```
> build: .
>
> volumes:
>
>   - ./:/app
>
> ports:
>
>   - "3030:3030"
>
> environment:
>
>   - MONGODB_URI="192.168.99.100/myapp"
>
> links:
>
>   - "mongo"
> ```
>
> mongo:
>
> ```
> image: "mongo"
>
> ports:
>
>   - "27017:27017"
>
> volumes_from:
>
>   - mongodata
> ```
>
> mongodata:
>
> ```
> image: tianon/true
>
> volumes:
>
>   - /data/db
> ```

I am trying to get the MONGODB_URI from inside a config object.
The console.log returns the expected result but I still get an error.

> class Config {
>
> ```
> constructor() {
>     this.port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
>     console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
>     this.databaseUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'localhost/myapp';
> }
> ```

The error I get is:

> Error: no hostname or hostnames provided in connection string
>   web_1        |     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:24:11)

If I try to use the URL directly, without relying on environmental variables, it works fine and I get a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently I just got my rubber duck style answer.

The issue was with the '- MONGODB_URI="192.168.99.100/myapp"'.
The value should not be wrapped in quotes.

I set it to "MONGODB_URI=192.168.99.100/myapp" and it works fine.